# Deleted Video Is Showing in Video Player in Android Studio Code

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am Creating a video Player in Android Studio and using Video View.
But I am facing a problem here
Suppose I have 5 Videos on phone, Then All the video is showing.
But when I remove 1 Video from my Phone. It Still visible Phone even I restart my application
Here s the screenshot of App
When there are 5 videos on my phone
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5GGP.png)
 When I delete One video
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSTXL.png)
Code How I access files from Internal and SD CARD

```
public void getFile(File directtory) {
        File[] listFile = directtory.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFile) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    getFile(file);
                } else {
                    permission = false;
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp4") || file.getName().endsWith(".mkv")  )


                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                            if (list.get(j).getName().equals(file.getName())) {
                                permission = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (permission) {
                            permission = false;
                        } else {
                            list.add(file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because your file is removed from storage but not from android media storage. use below function to delete video file from media storage.

```
public static void scanDeletedMedia(Context context, File file) {
    if (SDK_INT >= 19) {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "= ?", new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()});
    } else {
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.fromFile(file)));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you faced same problem in different  device?

Comment: Yes I face same issue